# How to find how much Cognito Forms free user storage remains

Tags: cognito-forms

I'm a free user, I recently published a survey with an upload file feature. I know the max storage capacity is 100MB.

Is it possible to know how many storage I got left, if for example, 10 entries have been uploaded already?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/).

Yes, you can check your current entry count, and storage space by going to the Organization Settings page. You can learn more about this in our [Help Content](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/153/account--organizations/organization-management/checking-usage).